# How to adjust buttons' text to buttons' size - Java's Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, layout-manager

I'm trying to create a simple GUI with a grid containing numbered buttons.
Problem is, the buttons' text will not adjust itself to the buttons' size.

let me first show you the code, so you'll see what I mean:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class SimpleGUI implements ActionListener {
    
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel grid;
    private JButton[] buttons;
    
    public SimpleGUI() {
        frame=new JFrame("Buttons grid");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        
        grid=new JPanel();
        buttons=new JButton[100];
        
        
        for (int i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i]=new JButton(Integer.toString(i+1));
            buttons[i].setActionCommand(Integer.toString(i+1));
            grid.add(buttons[i]);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
        
        frame.getContentPane().add(grid);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleGUI gui=new SimpleGUI();
        gui.go();
    }
    
    
    public void go() {
        grid.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));
        
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String buttonNum=e.getActionCommand();
        System.out.println("You've pressed "+buttonNum);
    }
    
}
```

The buttons are too small for the text to fit in, so instead of numbers, three dots will appear on them. (**...**)
Only when I expand the window (and thus expanding the buttons' dimension accordingly), the numbers appear on the buttons properly.
Is there a way to make the text adjust itself to the buttons' dimension so it'll always be visible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It indeed *is* possible to give a bit more space to the text within the buttons. The extra empty space around the text is controlled by the margins and that can be changed:

```
button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

If you want to make the buttons square by default, you can override their preferred size:

```
buttons[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i + 1)) {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension naturalSize = super.getPreferredSize();
        int sideLength = Math.max(naturalSize.width, naturalSize.height);
        return new Dimension(sideLength, sideLength);
    }
};
```

Then the initial layout will be square, when using `pack()` (which you should be using, as per Andrew Thompson's answer).

**Edit:** Changed the preferred size to take in account the button's normal preferred dimensions. (Credits to A. Thompson again).

Comment: @AndrewThompson well, a major part of the challenge in problem solving is to find the right question. By the looks of the supplied sscce (Yay! someone gave one), I decided to give some more information. It's possible that yours solves the actual issues and the rest are just artifacts of the sample.

Comment: Thank you both so much for the help.
kiheru - I didn't know that you can override a method like that...
I thought you have to extend a class if you want to override one of its methods...

Comment: @so.very.tired You're welcome. That's an anonymous class, you can read more about them from the excellent [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Answer (score 3):

Make the change seen below.

```
public void go() {
    grid.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));

    //frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

The trick here is not to change the buttons at all, but to get the GUI to adjust to the size of the buttons.  That is achieved by calling [`pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) which..

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents. ..